# Writing to linux console without using printk

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

This may be a stupid question, but is there a way to write to the linux console from within a driver without using printk (i.e. syslog)?

For instance, working in a linux driver, I need to output a single character as an event happens.  I'd like to output 'w' as an write event starts, and a 'W' when it finishes.  This happens frequently, so sending that through syslog isn't ideal.

Ideally, it would be great if I could just do the equivalent of printf("W") or putc('W') and have that simply go out the default console.

TIA
Mike

Comment: Assuming your syslog doesn't log kernel debugging, you could do: `printk(KERN_DEBUG, "message");`. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing to the console isn't something you want to do frequently. If `printk` is too expensive for you, you shouldn't try the console any way.

But if you insist:

Within `printk`, printing to the console is handled by `call_console_drivers`. This function finds the console (registered via `register_console`) and calls it to print the data. The actual driver depends on what console you're using. The VGA screen is one option, the serial port is another (depending on boot parameters).

You can try to use the functions in `console.h` to interact with the console directly. I don't know how hard it would be to make it work.

Comment: Perfect ugoren, that was what I needed.  I adapted this to get what I was looking for: http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/sercons/sercons.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, as there is no concept of "console" in the kernel (that is a userspace process). You may try other [kernel debugging options](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Debugging_Tips)

Comment: Sorry but there is a concept of console in the kernel, as ugoren explained in his answer.

Comment: there kernel has hooks to attach consoles to it, which is different